# Boot2docker v1.5.0 fails to start on OS X 10.10.3

Tags: macos, boot2docker

I'm running OS X 10.10.3.

boot2docker init creates the virtual machine.
boot2docker start starts the virtual machine, but it fails to connect to it with autodetection of the VM docker socket failing.
These are the last few lines of the verbose output:

```
Started.
Trying to get Docker socket one more time
2015/04/05 20:09:58 executing: /usr/bin/ssh ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i /Users/sarvagnan/.ssh/id_boot2docker docker@localhost grep tcp:// /proc/$(cat /var/run/docker.pid)/cmdline
Error requesting socket: exit status 255
2015/04/05 20:09:58 executing: /usr/bin/ssh ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i /Users/sarvagnan/.ssh/id_boot2docker docker@localhost tar c /home/docker/.docker/*.pem
Auto detection of the VM's Docker socket failed.
Please run boot2docker -v up to diagnose.
```

I've tried deleting the VM, downloading and starting again but that gives me the same output.

How do I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the log says, would you show us the result of `boot2docker -v up`?

Comment: I've put the complete output of boot2docker -v up as a gist
https://gist.github.com/sarvagnan/e8a2c420ac93fc04a166

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Did you already try executing `$(boot2docker shellinit)` before running `boot2docker up`?

Comment: I didn't think of doing that before `boot2docker up`. It doesn't work though.
The output of `$(boot2docker shellinit)` before `boot2docker up` is `error in run: VM "boot2docker-vm" is not running. (Did you run `boot2docker up`?)`.
The output of `$(boot2docker shellinit)` after `boot2docker up` is `error in run: Error requesting socket: exit status 255`.

Comment: Your boot2docker-vm might be in a strange state. Try open VirtualBox and delete that, then try `boot2docker -v init` and `boot2docker -v up` again.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It runs into the same problem.